# How to get path to Visual Studio 2010 user data folder?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

By default the user data for Visual Studio is stored at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010`.

I do not want to assume that the user chose to have his/her user data at a location which follows the above template.

Is there a way to programmatically get where Visual Studio is storing user data for a particular user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in the registry under:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

There are several Default*Location values, such as DefaultNewProjectLocation, but you are probably looking for VisualStudioLocation.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. May I ask where did you get this information from?

Comment: I opened up regedit and did a search for "Documents\Visual Studio". Keep in mind that this only for Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio 2008 has the same settings, but they are under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0". So when the next version of Visual Studio comes out, it will probably be under "11.0".

Comment: Cool, next time I'm in a similar situation I'll try doing something like this _before_ putting up a question :)